# User, UserManager, OO What is their assignment?

Tags: php

I was told that my following code was wrong, that instead it would be the UserManager, but I am wondering what would the User class contain then?

```
class User {

    protected $DBH;
    protected $STH;

    public function __construct($DBH) {
        $this->DBH = $DBH;
    }

    public function logged_in() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['userid'], $_SESSION['hash'])) {
            $hash = sha1($_SESSION['userid'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

            if ($_SESSION['hash'] == $hash)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare("SELECT id, banned, activated FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $this->STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        $this->STH->execute(array($username, $password));

        if (($row = $this->STH->fetch()) !== false)
            return $row;
    }

    public function create_account($username, $password, $email) {
        $activation_key = md5($username . $email);

        try {
            $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, activation_key, created) VALUES(:username, :password, :email, :activation_key, :created)");
            $this->STH->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $this->STH->bindParam(':password', $password);
            $this->STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $this->STH->bindParam(':activation_key', $activation_key);
            $this->STH->bindParam(':created', time());
            $this->STH->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            //$e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function check_record($field, $value) {
        $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE {$field} = ?");
        $this->STH->execute(array($value));

        $count = $this->STH->fetchColumn();

        if ($count !== false) {
            return (int)$count > 0;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function check_username($username) {
        return $this->check_record("username", $username);
    }

    public function check_email($username) {
        return $this->check_record("email", $username);
    }

    public function activate($key) {
        $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare("UPDATE users SET activated = 1, activation_key = null WHERE activation_key = ?"); 
        $this->STH->execute(array($key));

        return $this->STH->rowCount() > 0;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code?  What happens when you run it?  What's supposed to happen?

Comment: The code is working, indeed. It is just that I was told the "User class" wasn't suppose to DO this, instead it would be the "User" and you rather should have a "UserManager" for this stuff, I want an explanation on that... The code above was the code, I got the comment on.

Answer (score 1):

The person that told you that means that he thinks you should have 2 classes: A "dumb" User class which holds the information of a user, and a UserManager class, a class that deals with retrieving, saving, validating, etc...

This is not the rule, but the way that some people prefer.

Simple example

```
Class UserManager {

    function login( $username, $password ){} // return User object
    function create( $data ){} // returns User object
    function save( User $user ){}

}

Class User {

    public $username, $first_name, $last_name, $email;

}
```

`User` holds the data for a user while `UserManager` does all the querying.

Comment: I would like to add that the user class does not have to be "dumb". It could contain methods that relate to the particular user such as $user->addBadge($badge); or whatever. I think the main point is that a user class should only handle the concerns of a particular user.

Comment: It's really up to the person I prefer `UserManager->addBadge( $user, $badge );` because i like to keep all my sql in one place

Comment: adding a badge doesn't necessarily mean saving the badge to the db. If you save to the db every time you make a change to the model, you could be making a lot of unnecessary db calls.

Comment: I personally don't like to allow public access to properties. An object's internals should be handled by the object imho.

Comment: Well if you arent saving the badge immediately, then you are correct. I would add the badge to the user then save the user with the UserManager. I also like to have getters/setters, just didn't want to type them out.

Comment: How would a save method look like?

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns may suggest that methods like create_account have nothing to do with a particular user, and should not be in the user class.

This class also does not seem to contain any data about a particular user.

I would expect a user class to contain properties which contain the username and other user data, and methods that would specifically relate to the particular user.